# Sikuli to Lua script error, but got no error message at all

Tags: lua, sikuli

I'm new in Lua Script. Need Your Help.
I already scripting in sikuli and it's works. I use it for automated play Clash of Clans in Bluestack.

Because I plan to play Automated Clash of Clans in Bluestack without using Sikuli and hope it can work in minimize mode or backgroud mode, while in front layer I work something, e.g. work my paper with msword.

So, I learn that I can use AnkuLua to make that happens. Then I install AnkuLua in Bluestack and write the script in windows by LuaEdit 2010 app. then I load the script by AnkuLua.

The Problem is, show an error without any message.
like this:

[The Error Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZhwc.png)

I don't know where is my fault. Please Help me. I really appreciate for your help.

The code that i write in sikuli it show below:

### The SIKULI Script

```
def elexir():
    if exists(Pattern("elexir.png").similar(0.65)):
        click(Pattern("elexir.png").similar(0.65))
        wait(0.5)   

def coin():
    if exists("coin.png"):
        click("coin.png")
        wait(0.5)

while True:
    elexir()
    elexir()
    elexir()
    eleixir()
    elexir()
    coin()
    coin()
    coin()
    coin()
    coin()
```

just that.... it's work perfectly with Sikuli.

now, i'm try to do it in Lua with some adjustment.

### The Lua Script that I made is:

```
function Elexir()
    if exists(pattern("elexir.png")) then
        click(pattern("elexir.png"))
        wait(0.5)
    end
end

function Coin()
    if exists(pattern("coin.png")) then
        click(pattern("coin.png"))
        wait(0.5)
    end
end


while True do
    Elexir()
    Elexir()
    Elexir()
    Elexir()
    Coin()
    Coin()
    Coin()
    Coin()
end
```

Is i have a wrong perception in Lua Programming Language?

Before asking, I already change my script several times, and before the last script, there always a warning / message where the error source come from.
after fixing and fixing, I got test it by "Debug>Check Syntax" menu and "Debug>Start Debugging" menu, and no report that my script is error. seems work. but when I copy it to Bluestack. the error appear.

Any advice will appreciated.

Comment: I have never heard about Lua but I would doubt that any code written in one language will work as is in another. Second, I am absolutely convinced that Sikuli specific functions like `exists`, `pattern` and `click` won't exist as is.

Comment: `exists()`, `pattern()`, `click()` and `wait()` don't exist in standard Lua but I wouldn't be surprised if AnkuLua added those.

Answer (score 1):

Lua is case-sensitive try changing

```
while True do
```

to

```
while true do
```

otherwise it's not executing the loop because True is false and just exiting the script.